# Rapidly increasing system log in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.4, log, system.log

I have one Magento 2.2.4 website and used Template Monster Theme. but I am facing problem when any user accessing website continuously increase system log with below logs.

```
[2018-09-27 08:06:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-09-27 08:06:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.sidebarnav' element cannot be added as child to 'div.sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-09-27 08:06:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'brand.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-09-27 08:06:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.sidebarnav' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'div.sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-09-27 08:06:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'brand.sidebar' tries to reorder itself towards 'catalog.compare.sidebar', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-09-27 08:06:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.panel' tries to reorder itself towards 'header_info', but their parents are different: 'rd.navbar' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-09-27 08:06:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.switchers' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: you have to fixed this layout related issue . This magento 2 issue, there is no option to disable log

Comment: i know this is layout issue. but I am not able to find any solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you want to disable system.log and debug.log?

Comment: I want  to solve this layout issues

Comment: @mansi, Please share if you have solve this issue.